# Why was the New Orleans flag altered in NCIS New Orleans?

Tags: props, ncis-new-orleans

In the season finale "Checkmate Part 2" May 15, 2018, a flag was flying from a small rod attached to the upper railing outside the building were Pride's bar was located.

The flag resembled, but was different from, the city flag of New Orleans.

[image]

> The municipal flag of New Orleans is the representative banner of the city of New Orleans, Louisiana. The flag has a large white field that contains three gold fleurs-de-lis and is bordered on the top by a red stripe and from below by a blue stripe. The presence of the fleur-de-lis, a stylized depiction of a flower and a traditional French symbol, demonstrates the city's French heritage and strong ties to France.[2](http://The%20municipal%20flag%20of%20New%20Orleans%20is%20the%20representative%20banner%20of%20the%20city%20of%20New%20Orleans,%20Louisiana.%20The%20flag%20has%20a%20large%20white%20field%20that%20contains%20three%20gold%20fleurs-de-lis%20and%20is%20bordered%20on%20the%20top%20by%20a%20red%20stripe%20and%20from%20below%20by%20a%20blue%20stripe.%20The%20presence%20of%20the%20fleur-de-lis,%20a%20stylized%20depiction%20of%20a%20flower%20and%20a%20traditional%20French%20symbol,%20demonstrates%20the%20city's%20French%20heritage%20and%20strong%20ties%20to%20France.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_New_Orleans[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_New_Orleans)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_New_Orleans#/media/File:Flag_of_New_Orleans,_Louisiana.svg[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_New_Orleans#/media/File:Flag_of_New_Orleans,_Louisiana.svg)

In the episode the white area, by far the majority of the flag's surface, was colored yellow instead of white, and the yellow fleur-dei-lis were colored blue instead.  The upper and lower stripes might have been colored differently from in the New Orleans flag.

The production company should have been able to order a New Orleans flag of the size seen in the episode and have it shipped to the filming location for less than $ 100.00 total. So why go to the trouble of making a similar but different flag for use in the episode? Or are there flags like the one in the episode for sale somewhere?

Comment: Why do you think it's **intended** to be the flag of New Orleans? Americans often have *personal* flags from my reading. These are often based on local/regional/state flags.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I don't know any of my fellow Americans who have personal flags.  Having a personal flag is a great idea, and a great and relatively cheap way to impress other people.  But I expect that only a tiny minority of Americans have their own personal flags.

Comment: I know I'm pretty late to the party here. But it's a Mardi Gras themed one. So it's yellow, green and purple. https://www.pennantshop.net/mardi-gras

Comment: @TorreJosey You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, the regular [Flag of New Orleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_New_Orleans) is:

> Three yellow fleurs-de-lis on white field atop blue stripe and underneath red stripe, with the white field five times the width of the stripes.

However, what's shown is a version of the flag in [New Orleans' mardi gras traditional colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mardi_Gras_in_New_Orleans#Traditional_colors) - green, gold, and purple. There's less formal heraldry requirements and they're apparently a pretty common thing, if the number of different places to buy one on a [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mardi%20gras%20flag) is any indication.